# Renci sshnet issues re-connecting to device after reboot

Tags: c#, ssh

I'm using renci ssh heavily to automate processes on a remote machine. The problem I have is that when I need to reboot the remote machine, I'm getting errors reconnecting. I have a wrapper around the Ssh library components that creates an SSH session once, and then uses that SshClient object(once connected) to issue commands via calls to 'SshClient.CreateCommand/BeginExecute'.

When I send a command to reboot the device, I get the expected exception "An established connection was aborted by the server." and throw it away in this instance. I have the process that issued the reboot wait an appropriate amount of time for reboot to finish, and then attempt to reconnect. Then all I get are errors "Session operation has timed out" from then on. During this time I'm able to create an SSH connection separately (using any ssh client), but the code attempting to reconnect never works.

I tried:

- Disposing all components (SshClient.Dispose()) and re-initializing (new SshClient(params)), after the reboot and 'Session operation has timed out' exception.
- Re-using the same SshClient object and just calling the 'Connect()' function again (purposefully NOT disposing).
- Some combinations of the two.

Has anyone else dealt with an issue like this and found a suitable workaround? Some variable in some state that needs to be cleaned up for a new connection to work?